# How to change HTML table to an image

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, image

How can I return this html table to image and send through email?

```
def gsheet_get_location(plant_id):
    # função para ler planilha
    sa = gspread.service_account(filename="Service_acount.json")
    # reads the spreadsheet file
    sh = sa.open("Parameters Check")
    # read the work sheet
    wks = sh.worksheet("location_sensors")#nome da aba no google sheets
    wks_df = pd.DataFrame(wks.get_all_records())
    #print(wks_df[wks_df['Plant_id']=='12404'].head())
    plant_filtered = wks_df.query(f"Plant_id == {plant_id}")
    a = tabulate(plant_filtered, headers='keys',tablefmt='html')
    return a
```

Comment: what is `Html2Image()` in your code? Is this function from some module to convert HTML to image? What module?

Comment: I don't know modules to convert HTML to image, Eventually you could use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control browser and then you could display it in browser and take screenshot. But maybe it would be simpler to use HTML to generate PDF and later send PDF. (or maybe modules to generate PDF may have function to generate image from PDF)

Comment: I want to have the output as a table excel, or img, both would work the Html2Image is just a mistake

Comment: some mails can display html `<table>` - so you you could get dataframe as HTML `plant_filtered.to_html()` and put it directly in mail. OR you could get `plant_filtered.to_excel()` and send it as attachement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.